# using recursive method for trinary search

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I am writing a recursive method that, instead of carrying out a binary search algorithm, splits an array into three and uses a trinary search algorithm. I am fairly positive that my recursive case is correct, yet there seems to be a problem with my base case. The base case, which is made for if the array contains two or fewer values, is supposed to check non-recursively if the value is in the array and return the index. IF the value is not found, THEN it returns -1.

For reasons I can't figure out, this method is returning -1 no matter what. Regardless of the size of the array, or whether or not the array contains the value. Here is the method.

```
public static int trinarySearch(int[] array, int x, int low, int high) {

    if (high - low < 3) { //BASE CASE.
        for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
            if (array[i] == x) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    } else { //RECURSIVE CASE.

        int firstThird = low + (high - low) / 3;
        int secondThird = low + 2 * (high - low) / 3;

        if (x <= array[firstThird]) {
            return trinarySearch(array, x, low, firstThird - 1);
        } else if (x <= array[secondThird]) {
            return trinarySearch(array, x, firstThird + 1, secondThird - 1);
        } else { // must be (x > array[secondThird])
            return trinarySearch(array, x, secondThird + 1, high);
        }
    }
}
```

In my test code I am simply setting up an array as int[] array = {1, 2, .....}

Let's say I search for the int 2, and it is in the array. I set up an array in the test code and call the method as trinarySearch(array, 2, 0, array.length-1). It prints -1 every time. Is there something wrong with the method, or am I simply setting up my test code wrong?

Comment: The x <= array test looks incorrect.....

Comment: As @MitchWheat said, the tests in the recursive case are inconsistent with the limits on the recursive calls and with the base case stopping one _before_ `high`.  Rethink.  Insert some print statements or use a debugger to see where the error in your mental model lies.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up your logic for `low` and `high`. Typically, you would define the subarray under inspection to start at `low` (inclusive) and end at `high` (exclusive).

You use `high` inclusive (as I understand from your example call using `array.length-1`), but then loop like

```
for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
```

which does not visit `array[high]`.

The quick fix is to change `<` to `<=` and your code runs fine. However, I would recommend using the standard definition (high exclusive) because it also simplifies other parts of the code:

- You don't need any of the error-prone `+1` or `-1` index fixes (don't forget to change `<=` to `<` in your recursive case).
- `high-low` is the size of the subarray under inspection, so you can use `high-low <= 3` which more clearly shows that your base case handles arrays up to length 3.

Comment: It now works only for values in the first one-third of the array. The other two cases within the recursive case do not work, it still returns -1 when searching for a value in the last two-thirds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't understand Heuster answer. Here is what I would have done and it seems to me that Heuster was saying the same :

```
public static int trinarySearch(int[] array, int x, int low, int high) {

        if (high - low < 3) { //BASE CASE.
            for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
                if (array[i] == x) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        } else { //RECURSIVE CASE.
            int firstThird = low + (high - low) / 3;
            int secondThird = low + 2 * (high - low) / 3;

            if (x < array[firstThird]) {
                return trinarySearch(array, x, low, firstThird);
            } else if (x < array[secondThird]) {
                return trinarySearch(array, x, firstThird, secondThird);
            } else { // must be (x > array[secondThird])
                return trinarySearch(array, x, secondThird, high);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed one important condition in the recursive section which is `if(x==splitingIndex)`

I have change your code a little and its working
See the changes

```
public static int trinarySearch(int[] array, int x, int low, int high) {

    if (high - low < 3) { 
        //BASE CASE.
        for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
            if (array[i] == x) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    } else { //RECURSIVE CASE.

        int firstThird = low + (high - low) / 3;
        int secondThird = low + 2 * (high - low) / 3;

        if(x == array[firstThird])
        {
            return firstThird;
        }
        else if (x < array[firstThird]) {
            return trinarySearch(array, x, low, firstThird - 1);
        }

        if(x == array[secondThird])
        {
            return secondThird;
        }
        else if (x < array[secondThird]) {
            return trinarySearch(array, x, firstThird + 1, secondThird - 1);
        }



            return trinarySearch(array, x, secondThird + 1, high);
        }
    }
```